# How do do_action and add_action work?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to find what exactly do_action and add_action works. I already examine with add_action but for do_action i am trying as new now. This what i tried.

```
function mainplugin_test() {

$regularprice = 50;

if(class_exists('rs_dynamic')) {
$regularprice = 100;
}

// and doing further
//like i echoing the regular price
echo $regularprice; //It print 100 from this code

}
```

Now instead of placing few code in main file i am planning to create do_action to avoid code messing issue.

```
    function mainplugin_test() {

    $regularprice = 50;

    do_action('testinghook');

// and doing further
//like i echoing the regular price
echo $regularprice; //It should print 100 but it print 50

    }
```

so i created another function to point out that hook as something like

```
function anothertest() {
if(class_exists('rs_dynamic')) {
$regularprice = 100;
}
}
add_action('testinghook','anothertest');
```

Not sure how to add the lines of code to that hook that above function may work? As per i tried in my testing environment nothing helps. If i understand correct do_action is more like including a file??? If not please advise me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason it didn't print `100`, because `$regularprice` within `anothertest()` function is local to that function. The variable `$regularprice` used in parent `mainplugin_test()` function is not same as the variable used in `anothertest()` function, they are in separate scope.

So you need to either define the `$regularprice` in a global scope (which is not a good idea) or you can pass argument as a parameter to [`do_action_ref_array`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_action_ref_array). The `do_action_ref_array` is the same as `do_action` instead it accepts second parameter as array of parameters.

#### Passing as argument:

```
function mainplugin_test() {

    $regularprice = 50;
    
    // passing as argument as reference
    do_action_ref_array('testinghook', array(&$regularprice));

    echo $regularprice; //It should print 100

}

// passing variable by reference
function anothertest(&$regularprice) {
    if(class_exists('rs_dynamic')) {
        $regularprice = 100;
    }
}
// remain same
add_action('testinghook','anothertest');
```

Comment: Thanks @Rahil, I tried that code still it prints 50 do you know the reason of why it is not working?

Comment: Thanks It works great. I thought i can do by using do_action itself, i didn't go through do_action_ref_array Thanks again.

Answer (score 48):

`do_action` creates an action hook, `add_action` executes hooked functions when that hook is called.

For example, if you add the following in your theme's footer:

```
do_action( 'my_footer_hook' );
```

You can echo content at that location from functions.php or a custom plugin:

```
add_action( 'my_footer_hook', 'my_footer_echo' );
function my_footer_echo(){
    echo 'hello world';
}
```

You can also pass variables to a hook:

```
do_action( 'my_footer_hook', home_url( '/' ) );
```

Which you can use in the callback function:

```
add_action( 'my_footer_hook', 'my_footer_echo', 10, 1 );
function my_footer_echo( $url ){
    echo "The home url is $url";
}
```

In your case, you're probably trying to filter the value based on a condition. That's what filter hooks are for:

```
function mainplugin_test() {
    echo apply_filters( 'my_price_filter', 50 );
}

add_filter( 'my_price_filter', 'modify_price', 10, 1 );
function modify_price( $value ) {
    if( class_exists( 'rs_dynamic' ) )
        $value = 100;
    return $value;
}
```

**Reference**

- [add_action()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/)
- [do_action()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_action/)
- [add_filter()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_filter/)
- [apply_filters()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/apply_filters/)

**Edit (updated references links)**

Comment: Thanks for your reply :) From my case it is more like that do_action hook is inside function so please can you help me to make a working solution from my above code

Comment: Hi @diggy I tried your filter code looks like it is working, is the only way to use that function in filter instead of action?

Comment: If you're trying to modify a return value, filters are the way to go. Action hooks are generally used to print/insert content, or execute functions.

Comment: Isn't it the other way around? "_`do_action` creates an action hook, `add_action` executes hooked..._" this contradicts with the pages you linked.

Comment: I agree with @akinuri. do_action sounds more like executing the hook, where as add_action creating the hook

Comment: This is backward. add_action creates the hook and do action executes.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, the `add_action` is an action hook which is used to invoke an action (a registered handler) on a certain point depending on the action and the `do_action` is used to manually invoke that registered action. For example:

```
add_action('some_hook', 'handler_for_some_hook');
```

This handler will be invoked when you take or the script does the `some_action` but if you want you may invoke that action manually using the `do_action`. So, basically the `do_action` invokes the registered action hook when you call it. Check more on [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_action).

Comment: Hi Thanks for your reply, but my condition did you find any mistake that i invoke that action using do_action?

Answer (score 0):

//with do_action we create own tag(hook) use in wordpress
Ex. Here I added 1 custom function to call this
In add_action I added function name with any custom tag name
With do_action(my custom tag name)

```
function mywork()
{
    echo "display my name";
}

add_action('mytag','mywork');

do_action('mytag');
```

---add_action()---

hook-specific hook that will affect by **function**()

```
 add_action( hook, **function**() )
```

It will change functionality and behaviour of wordpress by Specific “hook” we can change it and functions method.