# How to add a custom header after the <body> element directly?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have created a very simple plugin to add custom header at the top of the page :

```
add_action('wp_head' , 'add_custom_header');

function add_custom_header(){
    //Some Code.
}
```

But that code is shown twice on the page , Maybe the `wp_head()` is added to that second place.

So I want to add that code in `the add_custom_header` function to be added just after the `<body>` element in every page on my website.

Comment: please share your header code because its not possible to print header twice in page using above action

Comment: @Jaydp , The header.php contains the primary menu that contains nav menu , The custom header I created is just an html element like a banner not a real header

Comment: it print twice because maybe you have entered "wp_head()" twice in a page

Comment: @Jaydp , Do you know a better action?

Comment: you can create and call a custom widget using a custom menu,  something like <aside>, create a widget and call a menu there then call into your theme wherever you like

Comment: better option to create/add your own action to header.php
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26781857/how-do-do-action-and-add-action-work